# How to get client connection object in tornado websocket, Python

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am using tornado websocket for simple test code.
In the test code, i want to get `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`.

For example, I used this way below.

```
class ConvPlayerInterface(object):

    class WebsocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

        client = None
        queue = ipcQueue.IpcQueue()

        def open(self):
            print 'new connection'
            self.client = self #in my simple code, it handles only one client.     

            self.write_message("Connection Open")

        def on_message(self, message):
            self.queue.put(message)

        def on_close(self):
            print 'connection closed'

    def __init__(self, url='/ws'):
        self.application = tornado.web.Application([(url, self.WebsocketHandler),])
        self.httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(self.application)
        self.httpServer.listen(8888)

        self.queue = self.WebsocketHandler.queue

        self.ioLoop = threading.Thread(target = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)

    def start(self):
        self.ioLoop.start()

    def get(self):
        return self.queue.get()

    def put(self, command):
        self.WebsocketHandler.client.write_message(command)
```

But the point when it calls `self.WebsocketHandler.client.write_message(command)` in `put()` method, Python says `client` is Non type.

Any advice?

And how usually it is used to get client connection handler object in `tornado`?

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code

```
 def put(self, command):
        self.WebsocketHandler.client.write_message(command)
```

you are accessing to WebsocketHandler class, not a class member. 
And the "client" attribute of WebsocketHandler is None, as expected.

WebsocketHandler instance will be created for each request tornado will accept, so there can be several websocket handlers simultaneously.

If you really want to have handle only one connection - you can do something like this:

```
class ConvPlayerInterface(object):
    the_only_handler = None

    class WebsocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

        client = None
        queue = ipcQueue.IpcQueue()

        def open(self):
            print 'new connection'
            ConvPlayerInterface.the_only_handler = self
            self.write_message("Connection Open")

        def on_message(self, message):
            self.queue.put(message)

        def on_close(self):
            ConvPlayerInterface.the_only_handler = None
            print 'connection closed'

    def __init__(self, url='/ws'):
        self.application = tornado.web.Application([(url, self.WebsocketHandler),])
        self.httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(self.application)
        self.httpServer.listen(8888)

        self.queue = self.WebsocketHandler.queue

        self.ioLoop = threading.Thread(target = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)

    def start(self):
        self.ioLoop.start()

    def get(self):
        return self.queue.get()

    def put(self, command):
        if self.the_only_handler is not None
            self.the_only_handler.write_message(command)
```